# Pycharm cant run WSL 2 interpreter because Source Root is marked as a windows dir instead of WSL dir

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, interpreter, wsl-2

When using the WSL python interpreter, Pycharm attempts to `cd` to the project Source root folder.
However it is using the full windows path: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\ubuntu\code\my-repo` 
Instead of the needed WSL path: `~/code/my-repo`

resulting the following error :

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu1804.exe run "export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 && export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 && export PYTHONPATH=\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\ubuntu\code\my-repo:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/202.6397.98/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/202.6397.98/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display && export PYCHARM_HOSTED=1 && export PYCHARM_DISPLAY_PORT=63342 && cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\ubuntu\code\my-repo && /home/ubuntu/code/my-repo/venv/bin/python '//wsl$/Ubuntu-18.04/home/ubuntu/code/my-repo/code.py'"
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: \wsl$Ubuntu-18.04homeubuntucodemy-repo: No such file or directory
```

---

Pycharm Professional 2020.2

Comment: apparently it's a known [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43023)